# Validate strings in an if statement but compensate for spelling mistakes

Tags: php

I'm in the process of creating a conditional if statement to display certain data if information is input into a text field.. The only block i've encountered is possible user-error.. So i'm wondering if theres a way to compensate for spelling mistakes?

```
if (isset($_POST['Data_Cont'])){
    if ($_POST['Data_Cont'] === "Alpha239d"){
        echo "Displaying Form Specific Data"; 
    }
}
```

But how to compensate for spelling mistakes?

Comment: A different approach might be auto-completion suggestions to reduce typos.

Answer (score 1):

Three possibles:

1. Use a dropdown of available options rather than a text input.
2. Make arrays of exact and near match strings and use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) rather than === for the conditional statement
3. Use the [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function in the conditional statement allowing for a set number of differences in the string compared to what is expected, however this may give false positives depending on how close different words you are expecting are to each other